# Custom label for Sitecore Form fields

Tags: sitecore-forms

Sitecore Provides OOTB field 'Label' to provide the field label, checkbox label etc.
I need to customize this, so that the 'Label' data can be taken from a sitecore item.

For example: I need to add a check box in form, but need to take the label from a sitecore item. How should i implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need your custom view file, `myLabel.cshtml` file,
Inside the file you can read the item and place the text.

To integrate that view you need a new custom control button where you can drag your custom control and drop it on the form.

You might also need a new field in the description of that custom control, to allow the user to select the item. In the .cshtml file you will get the item and get the text and place it in the label.

To do all that please consult this articles:

https://mohamed-ahmed-abdullah.github.io/SitecoreBlog/docs/Forms/

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action.html

I hope this help you